# How to measure similarity between parallel vectors?

Tags: machine-learning, geometry, recommendation-engine

I am building a recommendation system.
In order to measure similarity between a User's Profile Vector and an Item Vector, we can use the Cosine Similarity.

Lets say an Item is represented as a vector with *n* components , where each component is a feature of the Item. (all the features are in the range of 0-5)

Consider

> User Profile Vector is [2,0,2,2]
>
> Item1 Feature Vector is [4,0,4,4]
>
> Item2 Feature Vector is [1,0,1,1]

Here `cosinesimilarity(User,Item1)` is equal to `cosinesimilarity(User,Item2)` which is 1 .
This is because all of them are indeed similar.

But Item1 is better than  Item2 for the User as it has higher valued features.

Using the `dotproduct` as a similarity metric will give the desirable results in the above case.

Most of the lecture course materials and implementations use CosineSimilarity metric .What is the proper way to choose a similarity calculating function ?

Answer (score 0):

You might search for the cross product, or vector product.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

With that you calculate the surface of the rhomb opened by the two vectors, if parallel (or identical) - so similar - the result will be 0. The larger the difference there is between those vectors the higher will be the result.

Answer (score 0):

"But Item1 is better than Item2 for the User as it has higher valued features": this is what you say, but you have to question this statement.

Given a User's Profile vector, you could sketch the locus of the Feature vectors that you consider equally similar to it.

In the case of the cosine, the locus is a cone with apex at the origin, and an aperture angle with a cosine equal to the similarity level. The cone opens with increasing dissimilarity.

If you take a dot product instead, the locus is a hyperplane perpendicular to the Profile vector. The plane moves by translation.

The Euclidean distance will give you a sphere centered at the endpoint of the Profile vector. The sphere inflates.

...

It is up to you to make up your mind about the global properties of a suitable similarity measure.